# Does Corda node explorer work with Tokens?

Tags: corda

Does Corda node explorer work with Tokens?
I am able to connect to the the stockpaydividend coradapp via Corda node explorer.
Everything seems to be working fine except the Vault Explorer.
When clicking on the vault explorer, I get the following error.

*Described type with descriptor net.corda:Ilpg7fRBQWWGmwpkEi3Mtg== was expected to be of type class
com.r3.corda.lib.tokens.contracts.types.TokenType but was class  com.r3.corda.lib.tokens.contracts.types.TokenPointer*

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ideally yes the node explorer doesn't really care about the data types of what's used in flows or states or anything like that.

This looks like it MIGHT be a bug so if you haven't modified the CorDapp it would be worth making an issue on github.

link:
https://github.com/corda/node-explorer/issues/new